# Ansible: passing a dictionary as a function argument

Tags: ansible, yaml

I have the following construction:

```
        lookup(
          'template',
          'some_template.j2',
          template_vars=dict(some_dictionary_1=dict(some_dictionary_2))
        )
```

I'd like to make it a little bit more readable (for myself), so I'd like rephrase these `=`-expressions to something like that:

```
        lookup(
          'template',
          'some_template.j2',
          {
            'template_vars': {
              'some_dictionary_1': dict(some_dictionary_2)
            }
          }
        )
```

Of course, the above snippet doesn't work.

Would anyone be so kind as to help me to understand how I can get rid of `=`s in this case? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you were very close, with the distinction that [`template_vars` is a python keyword argument](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/5/collections/ansible/builtin/template_lookup.html#parameter-template_vars) (aka "kwarg") and thus needs to be in the `=` syntax, but the rest of it is fair game to be in a dict literal syntax

```
- debug:
    msg: >-
        lookup(
          'template',
          'some_template.j2',
          template_vars={
              'some_dictionary_1': dict(some_dictionary_2)
            }
        )
```

although, if it really, really bugs you that much, you can be extra sneaky by using python's [`**` dict unpacking syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#dictionary-displays):

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: >-
        lookup(
          'template',
          'some_template.j2',
          **{'template_vars': {
              'some_dictionary_1': dict(some_dictionary_2)
            }
          }
        )
```

but for the sake of your future colleagues, best not to do that :-D

Comment: Lots of thanks to you!